# How do I make a horizontal sitemap using UL?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've been trying for hours now to figure out how to make a footer sitemap just like in this webpage [www.telia.dk](http://www.telia.dk) (in the bottom) using CSS and UL/LI.

I'm a CSS noob, so please help me out.

Here's an example tree...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Color/li>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Blue</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Fruit</li>
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Lemon</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Weekdays</li>
            <li>Monday</li>
            <li>Friday</li>
            <li>Saturday</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Numbers</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any idae how to make my UL above look like the one at the bottom of [www.telia.dk](http://www.telia.dk)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way is something like this (`.hMenu` is the outer `ul` here):

```
.hMenu > li { /* for direct childs (>) of .hMenu that are li-s */
    /* inline-block will make them inline but also block - the best of both :) */
    display: inline-block; 
    /* they will align themselves to each other's top */
    vertical-align: top; 
    /* just a little horizontal margin */
    margin: 0 10px; 
}
.hMenu ul li:first-child { /* for the first li-s in inner ul-s */
     /* we make them bold */
     font-weight: bold; 
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xc6U/)

Please note that this is not something that can be readily used in production, it certainly won't work in IE6/7. You can find great [compatibility tables on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html).

Instead of `display: inline-block;` you can also consider using floats.

Comment: COOL! Thanks. Perfect!!! I just love this site and you guys! :) I've been strugling for hours now and within few minutes you answer my question perfectly! I really appreciate it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like **[this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/Bsamc/)**?

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Color</li>
                <li>Red</li>
                <li>Blue</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Fruit</li>
                ...
```

CSS:

```
#footer ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#footer>ul>li {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
}
#footer ul li ul li:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at their code, all you really need is

```
ul > li {
    float:left;
    width:140px;
}
```

that is to be applied to the **first** `ul`'s `li`

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzpcW/**